# QGIS - Removing a section of a raster

Tags: raster

I have a raster layer showing wind speeds over the entire of New Zealand but only want it to show the ocean component. I have a vector file of the mean high tide mark (basically the outline of NZ - green outline).

Am I able to remove the section inside the vector file from the raster?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GRASS`'s tool called `r.mask.vect` and select the `Create inverse` mask option, like so:

[image: example]

This is the initial raster image:

[image: initial raster]

This is the polygon (i.e., the mask):

[image: polygon]

And this is the (inversed) masked raster:
[image: masked]

QGIS version 3.34.4-Prizren.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried what you said but the output layer, "Masked", didn't display anything. Do I need to change any of the other parameters?

Comment: No you don't. Are you using a polygon as a mask or a line?

Comment: Ahh that was the issue, it looked like a polygon but was in fact a line. All sorted, thankyou for your help Nikos!